How to hear the voice in the headphone?
There are audio ports in the normal pc case's front panel.

No audio ports in my mini pc case's front panel.

I add a built-in usb slot audio in the motherboard.

Check the usb device:
lsusb | grep -i audio
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1b3f:2008 Generalplus Technology Inc. USB Audio Device

The usb audio device works fine.I can only plug my headphone in the real panel.Now no voice in the headphone.
To check the headphone when plugged in the rear panel's audio port.



How can hear voice in my headphone?

You should find the ports on the back of the pc. I suggest you read the motherboards manual.
